# If statement returns in CLISP

Tags: loops, if-statement, common-lisp

So I currently am trying to write a function in CLISP. What I want to do is cause the program to stop and do something on a certain condition, but continue through a loop while the condition is not true. So

```
(do ((i 0 (1+ i)))
      ((equal rows i))
    ;;loop body
    ;;for each row, look at a column
    (do ((j 0 (1+ j)))
    ((equal cols j))
      ;;loop body
      (if
       (equal (get-value board i j) 0) (do ((lst (poss(get-row board i)) (cdr lst)))
                                        ((null lst)  nil)
                                        (return-from solve-driver(set-value board i j (car lst)))))
```

so basically I've got two nested loops. on the case of the if statement being true, I'm recursively trying to run this function, but if the statement is not true, it needs to continue running through the loop. Instead, the if statement evaluates and returns nil. Is there some sort of continue function I can use to keep this going? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realized that the issue was within the loop itself. If statements are skipped in CLISP if there is no second clause for return. So the issue was not within the if-statement itself, but with outside methods as well as the recursion.